# Expected u3, but every varable is a u8

Tags: types, zig

I am confused.

Here is a minimal reproducable sample:

```
pub fn main() void {
  const firstByte: u8 = 0b10000000;
  var col: u8 = 0;
  const bytes: u8 = 1;
  var colByte: u8 = bytes & (firstByte >> col);
  _ = colByte;
}
```

When compiling this, I get the following error:

```bash
An error occurred:
playground/playground1330700213/play.zig:5:43: error: expected type 'u3', found 'u8'
  var colByte: u8 = bytes & (firstByte >> col);
                                          ^~~
playground/playground1330700213/play.zig:5:43: note: unsigned 3-bit int cannot represent all possible unsigned 8-bit values
referenced by:
    callMain: /usr/local/bin/lib/std/start.zig:604:17
    initEventLoopAndCallMain: /usr/local/bin/lib/std/start.zig:548:51
    remaining reference traces hidden; use '-freference-trace' to see all reference traces
```

I don't get why it says it's expecting a u3 since all variable used are u8s.

The note makes it even more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Table-of-Operators):

> a >> b
>
> Bit Shift Right.
>
> - `b` must be comptime-known or have a type with log2 number of bits as `a`.

In other words, the compiler expects you to use `u3` because it can only represent 8 possible values, the exact number of bits the `u8` type has.

Simply change `col` from `u8` to `u3` or use an [`@intCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#intCast):

```
var colByte: u8 = bytes & (firstByte >> @intCast(col));
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. The note was kinda confusing in the error message.

Comment: I agree, it is a bit confusing.